# RSS pubDate failing validation

Tags: php, rss, timestamp

I have a string date that I want to convert to RSS pubDate in PHP.

`<?php echo date('r',strtotime('14/10/2015 2:58:27 a.m.'));?>`

But the above is giving me some wild results in the sixties.

Is 'r' not sufficient in this situation? Do I need to do some fancy regex to match my string?

Comment: You need a specific date or just the  current date ?

Comment: A specific date, that will arrive as a string like above:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rss `pubDate` uses the [RFC 2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) standards. Use the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rss) and take advantage of the predefined constant `DateTime::RSS`

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");
    $raw = "14/10/2015 2:58:27 a.m.";
    $raw = str_replace(".", "", $raw); //am/pm
    if(strpos($raw,'am') !== false){ $ampm = "a";}else{$ampm = "A";}
    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y g:i:s $ampm", $raw);
    echo $time->format(DateTime::RSS);
    //Wed, 14 Oct 2015 02:58:27 +0000
?>
```

---

**P.S.**: Change the `default_timezone` to yours - http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

---

**Live Demo**

https://eval.in/450161

Comment: I guess the OP code wasn't working due to the wrong format of a.m. But it's just a guess because I didn't test it.

Comment: Actually it works fine but has a 5hr offset in my browser:/

Comment: No prob, You just need to set the `date_default_timezone_set`, I'll update the answer, what's your timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell php the date is not in yyyy-mm-dd format (or mm-dd-yyyy) so strtotime can handle it.

try

```
<?php echo date('r',strtotime('14/10/2015 2:58:27 a.m.' . 'GMT'));?>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get the same result. Was all you changed adding the GMT argument?